# Cordova 4.1.2 and cordova file plugin 1.3.3 work fine in devices but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, google-chrome

I have added the cordova file plugin 1.3.3 to our Cordova 4.1.2 project. When I run the project in iOS or Android devices the app starts up correctly. In de logs I see that the file system is correctly loaded. But when I try this in the development browser Chrome 43.0.2357 it will fail (deviceready has not fired after 8 seconds.)

This is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("yooooooo");
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    console.log("gotFS");
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    console.log("gotFileEntry");
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
        console.log("contents of file now 'some sample text'");
        writer.truncate(11);
        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
            console.log("contents of file now 'some sample'");
            writer.seek(4);
            writer.write(" different text");
            writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
                console.log("contents of file now 'some different text'");
            }
        };
    };
    writer.write("some sample text");
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

I also tried using all previous versions of the file plugin, but that did not make a difference. Only with file plugin 1.1.0 my project started correctly, but then the gotFS will never be called.

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Jasper Swart

Comment: device ready only fires on cordova apps, not on chrome

Comment: when I uninstall the file plugin then deviceready is called also in Chrome

Comment: did you install browser platform?

Comment: no where can I find that? i see you want me to add the browser platform to the app

Comment: just put "cordova platform add browser" (without the "")

Comment: i did that and installed all plugins into the browser platform, but now i have a different error: "Error initializing Network Connection: Missing Command Error"